# Is not authorized to perform SNS:Publish when worker is on another aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an sns topic called club, and I want to publish a message with my worker environment. It works when the worker Elastic Beanstalk is in my account. However, I tried deploying it on another account and it is not authorized to do so. I also have added access policy towards the topic.

I am also using an educate account.

I am at a loss on how to fix this.

Here is the access policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "grant_everyone_access",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:Receive",
        "SNS:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:club"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details. For instance what is `111111111111` account? Is it sns topic owner account or not? What is `club?` What errors do you get? How do you attempt to publish to the sns topic from the second account?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details in relation to what is in Account-1, what is in Account-2, where you are putting the permissions and what action you are wanting to perform. Thank you!